# OUTER JOIN Works in one direction but not the other

Tags: postgresql, join

This started as a Rails app question but has evolved as I need to do a raw SQL query.  My title may be off but it's the best I could come up with.

Here is my data:

```
SELECT 
     "model_locations".* 
FROM 
     "model_locations"

    +----+---------------------+-------------+
    | id |            model_id | location_id |
    +----+---------------------+-------------+
    |    | 17                  | 50          |
    |    | 17                  | 51          |
    |    | 10                  | 24          |
    |    | 19                  | 11          |
    |    | 19                  | 5           |
    |    | 19                  | 51          |
    +----+---------------------+-------------+
    6 rows in set

SELECT 
    "models"."id", "models"."location_from_id", "models"."location_to_id" 
FROM 
    "models"'

+----+------------------+----------------+
| id | location_from_id | location_to_id |
+----+------------------+----------------+
| 17 | 1                | 5              |
| 18 | 50               | 24             |
| 10 | 3                | 8              |
| 1  | 50               | 11             |
| 19 | 1                | 5              |
| 20 | 1                | 11             |
| 21 | 11               | 5              |
+----+------------------+----------------+
7 rows in set
```

So for example:

```
Model 17 has Locations 50, 51 AND 1 ,5 
Location 11 has Models 19, 1 AND 20, 21
```

So I can find the Model Locations:

```
SELECT 
    "locations".* 
FROM 
    "locations" 
    LEFT JOIN "model_locations" ON "locations"."id" = "model_locations"."location_id" 
WHERE 
    "model_locations"."model_id" = 17 OR "locations"."id" IN (1,5)
```

This works great - I get my 4 locations however I can't get the reverse to work:

```
SELECT 
     "models".* 
FROM 
     "models" 
WHERE 
     "models"."location_from_id" = 11 OR "models"."location_to_id" = 11 
INNER JOIN "model_locations" ON "model_locations"."model_id" = "models"."id" 
WHERE 
     "models_locations"."location_id" = 11'
```

This fails at the INNER JOIN:

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INNER"
```

I am pretty weak on my SQL but I don't get while this doesn't work.  I have tried several variations etc. and am sure I don't have a typo.

I need the SQL that will get me Models 19, 1 AND 20, 21 related to Location 11

**UPDATE**

I should really not stay up late working on this stuff.  This seems to work and a swear I tried this:

```
SELECT 
     "models".* 
FROM 
     "models" 
LEFT JOIN "model_locations" ON "model_locations"."model_id" = "models"."id" 
WHERE 
     "models_locations"."location_id" = 11'
     OR
     "models"."location_from_id" = 11
     OR
     "models"."location_to_id" = 11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two (plus 1) - seemingly independent - relationships between `models` and `locations`. One relationship is in `model_locations` and the other two in `models`.

I find both your queries to be incorrect because they don't examine the relationships independently. If there is a relationship (between a model and a location) only in one of these two tables, the query will not return any. Using `LEFT` joins might be possible but seems inappropriate, too.

I'd use simple `OR` conditions with `EXISTS` subqueries or a `UNION`:

- Final all locations of a certain model (`17`):

  ```
  SELECT 
      loc.* 
  FROM 
      locations AS loc 
  WHERE EXISTS
        ( SELECT 1
          FROM model_locations AS ml
          WHERE ml.model_id = 17 
            AND ml.location_id = loc.id
        )
     OR EXISTS
        ( SELECT 1
          FROM models AS mod
          WHERE mod.id = 17  
            AND loc.id IN (mod.location_from_id, mod.location_to_id)
        ) ;
  ```
- Final all models of a certain location (`11`):

  ```
  SELECT 
      mod.* 
  FROM 
      models AS mod 
  WHERE EXISTS
        ( SELECT 1
          FROM model_locations AS ml
          WHERE ml.location_id = 11 
            AND ml.model_id = mod.id
        )
     OR 11 IN (mod.location_from_id, mod.location_to_id)
   ;
  ```

Comment: That works and is likely better than what I had.  I was going to say it was more complex but in my first SQL that worked I had to specify the `1,5` (which was ok in my situation) but your solution is more complete.  My only comment is the second WHERE should be `WHERE mod.id = 17`

Comment: @DanTappin thnx, corrected. By the way, you can edit (or suggest edits) your self, in other people's posts!

Answer (score 2):

I have just copied/pasted your INNER JOIN query - see below.
You have coded a WHERE clause in the wrong place. 
Keep the second WHERE (at the end of your query),
remove the one before the INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT "models".* 
FROM "models" 
WHERE "models"."location_from_id" = 11 OR "models"."location_to_id" = 11 
INNER JOIN "model_locations" 
   ON "model_locations"."model_id" = "models"."id" 
WHERE "models_locations"."location_id" = 11
```

It should be:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ... INNER JOIN ... ON
WHERE

SELECT "models".* 
FROM "models" 
INNER JOIN "model_locations" 
   ON "model_locations"."model_id" = "models"."id" 
WHERE "models_locations"."location_id" = 11
```

-- update:
Sorry about this - the WHERE was just sticking out like a sore thumb...
Apparently, you are working with 3 tables, but you've only shown us (parts of) 2 of them in your initial question.  If my assumption is correct, then the tables you are dealing with are: MODELS, MODEL_LOCATIONS, and LOCATIONS.

If this is the case, I suggest that you just join them all together, and then select whichever column you need.  Use "table aliases" ie one or 2 letters as "shortcuts" for table names, in order to make your query easier to read/code.

Do something like:

```
select 
      -- whichever columns you need eg M.id, ML.model_id
from models M 
  inner join model_locations ML on (M.id = ML.model_id)
  inner join locations L        on (L.id = ML.location_id)
where ... -- whatever condition(s) return(s) the correct rows
```

In any case, the WHERE needs to be written after the FROM.

Comment: Except if I remove the WHERE before the join I lose those results.  Note the  location_from_id and location_to_id and NOT just location_id